# "\n" in strings not working

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, newline

I have this little piece of code for my sort of Operating System:

```
print("Type your document below.")
print("Press enter to save.")
print("Type \\n for a new line.")
file=input()
print("Enter a file name...")
filename=input()
outFile = open(filename, "w+")
outFile.write(file)
outFile.close()
```

but when I run this code (which is in a def), say I enter something like this:

```
foo \n bar
```

because enters dont work when recieving input from the users, so you have to use \n.

the file turns out as:

```
foo \n bar
```

instead of:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: in a string prevents actually making a new line and instead of `Type (new line) for a new line` it is `Type \n for a new line`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Martijn explained you'll need to process the replacements yourself. The easiest way to do that is literally with the `.replace` method:

```
>>> print(input('Enter \\n for newline: ').replace('\\n', '\n'))
Enter \n for newline: This is my \nnewline
This is my 
newline
```

This will work fine for the `\n` escape sequence, but if you want others (e.g. `\t`) then you'll need to implement that yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, and what about writing to a file? Would the same thing work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. why not try it?

Comment: This approach will corrupt escaped backslashes (e.g. user inputs the characters "yes\\no").  Martijn's alternative approach of calling input within a loop is better.

Answer (score 20):

`\n` is an escape sequence that only works in *string literals*. `input()` does not take a string literal, it takes the text the user inputs and doesn't do any processing on it so anyone entering `\` followed by `n` produces a string of two characters, a backslash and the letter `n`, not a newline.

You'll have to do your own processing of such escapes yourself:

```
file = file.replace(r'\n', '\n')
```

Here I used a raw string literal, which also doesn't support escapes sequences, to define the literal backslash `\` followed by a `n`.

Alternatively, repeatedly ask users for a new filename, until they are done:

```
lines = []
print('Type in your document, followed by a blank line:')
while True:
    line = input("> ")
    if not line:
        break
    lines.append(line)
file = '\n'.join(lines)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lines = []
>>> print('Type in your document, followed by a blank line:')
Type in your document, followed by a blank line:
>>> while True:
...     line = input("> ")
...     if not line:
...         break
...     lines.append(line)
...
> foo
> bar
>
>>> lines
['foo', 'bar']
>>> '\n'.join(lines)
'foo\nbar'
```

Comment: and how would i do that?

Answer (score 7):

Note that if you want to support Python-style strings (with not only `\n` but also `\t`, `\r`, `\u1234`, etc.), you should use `codecs.decode` with the `unicode_escape` handler:

```
contents = input()
contents = codecs.decode(contents, "unicode_escape")
```

Note that this will change

```
foo\nbar\\nbash\u1234
```

to

```
foo
bar\nbashሴ
```

You will also want to handle errors. You can do this either by catching `UnicodeDecodeError` or by using an error replacement policy:

```
contents = input()
contents = codecs.decode(contents, "unicode_escape", errors="replace")
```

Sadly this seems to mess with unicode characters:

```
codecs.decode("α", "unicode_escape")
#>>> 'Î±'
```

The simplest fix I know of is to first escape with `raw_unicode_escape`:

```
contents = input()
contents = contents.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
contents = contents.decode("unicode_escape")
```

This is probably far more complicated than you need, so I suggest not actually doing this.

Comment: The "mess with" is actually an `"α".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')`. This is not really a legitimate use case for `unicode_escape` nor `raw_unicode_escape` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)).

Comment: @wim Hence the preceding `.encode`. What makes it illegitimate?

Comment: This idea of using a raw_unicode_escape encode followed by a unicode_escape decode is doing a whole bunch of other stuff unrelated to the original question (and can cause information loss). For example consider using this with inputs "s\t" and "s\\t", both will be transformed into an s + tab character in the output rather than giving an s + backslash + t for the latter. For handling literal newlines during an `input()` interactivity, which is what the question was really about, Martijn's answer seems much better approach!

Comment: @wim I did say “if you want to support Python-style strings”, and in Python `"s "` and `"s\t"` are the same string. That's intended. I agree it's overkill if you *only* care about newlines.

Comment: @wim The r-strings were presumably because I was testing strings that included backslashes, though, yes, that string doesn't need it. `codecs` was used because it lets you decode `str`s, though it's not needed for the final example. I've removed it now.

Comment: I also think ‘caching’ was a typo of ‘catching’.

Comment: The answer is in better shape now. I don't think you got the main point here - `"s "` and `"s\t"` are the same string, no disagreement there, but `"s\\t"` is a different one! It may not be consequential for this use case, since it doesn't seem possible to get the return value of `"s\\t"` from an `input` call. Regardless, I still think looping on `input` is nicer than requiring users to literally enter escape sequences in the data.

Comment: Also, encode("raw_unicode_escape") + decode("unicode_escape") was helpful for me when restoring lists of strings from their string representations.