# Read a txt file with \n in between the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a txt file that contain the operation hour of the different stall.

I am trying to read the txt file in dictionary in python.

The txt file is something like this

Chicken Rice| Mon - Fri: 08:30 to 17:00\n Sat: 09:00 to 15:00\n Sun & PH: Closed
Western Food| Mon - Fri: 10:00 to 19:00\n Sat, Sun & PH: Closed

I have tried using:

```
stalls = {}
with open("Operation Hour.txt") as f:
for line in f:
    (key, value) = line.split("| ")
    stalls[key] = value
```

But the outcome does not split to new line. Instead it show "\n" in the output which is not what I want.

It show:

```
Chicken Rice     Mon - Fri: 08:30 to 17:00\n Sat: 09:00 to 15:00\n Sun & PH: Closed
```

Instead of:

```
Chicken Rice     Mon - Fri: 08:00 to 19:00
                       Sat: 09:00 to 15:00
                       Sun & PH: Closed
```

Please help me in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to implement it yourself.
Take a look at this answer. It could help.

["\n" in strings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401450/n-in-strings-not-working)

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I just have to add in
line = line.replace(r"\n", "\n")