# A new line isn't being created with \n and I don't know why

Tags: python-3.x

The title sums it up really. I've got a string inside an array which is supposed to be for a multiple choice question game in a tutorial I'm following.

\n is to create a new line right? Look here.

When the tutor does it, and I'm absolutely copy/pasta his method, he gets line breaks, but me, no. I have the same version of python and am on Windows

```
question_prompts = [
"What color are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Black\n\n",
"What color are bananas?\n(a) Red\n(b) Pink\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
"What color are Strawberries?\n(a) Pink\n(b) Red\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
]
print(question_prompts)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\n" in strings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401450/n-in-strings-not-working)

Comment: The question_prompts[] are values for my questions class def __init__(self, prompt, answer).

I use question_prompts as questions.prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Printing a list uses the elements' [`__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr) method. For strings, this means "special characters" (read "control characters") are ignored (in other words, the strings' "raw" form is printed).

If you want `\n` to be printed while the strings are in a list, you have several options, two of which are:

- Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

  ```
  print('\n'.join(question_prompts))
  ```
- Use a loop:

  ```
  for question in question_prompts:
      print(question)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This also works.

```
question_prompts = [
"What color are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Black\n\n",
"What color are bananas?\n(a) Red\n(b) Pink\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
"What color are Strawberries?\n(a) Pink\n(b) Red\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
]
print(question_prompts[0])
print(question_prompts[1])
print(question_prompts[2])
```

And gives the output:

```
What color are apples?
(a) Red/Green
(b) Purple
(c) Black


What color are bananas?
(a) Red
(b) Pink
(c) Yellow


What color are Strawberries?
(a) Pink
(b) Red
(c) Yellow
```